# Gnome Boxes unable to connect to internet on VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, gnome-boxes

I am trying to set up a Lab for RHCSA and have 3 virtual machines running Centos 7. I can't get the machines to see each other on the network, I also can't ping anything from the VM as well as I can't reach any VM from the host running Ubuntu 16.04. How do I configure the network card? I have tried modifying my existing connection of my ethernet card on my local host to Share connection but it still does not work. How do I connect my VMs to internet?
I have tried this:

```
nmcli device connect eth0
nmcli connection down eth0
nmcli connection up eth0
nmcli device status # connected
ip a s # 10.0.2.15
ping www.o2.pl
<no action>
```

All virtual machines get the same IP address of 10.0.2.15/24. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using for your VM manager? What version of Ubuntu are you running? What is RHCSA, and is that relevant to your question? Guessing at a solution, you may want to consider checking to make sure that your VMs are configured in "bridged" network mode. In this mode, each VM should be seen by the LAN as a separate device. For a good explanation of a bridged network configuration, see: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Answer (score -3):

I've just worked out a very simple solution to my problem:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-boxes
suod apt-get install virtualbox
```